# Mixpanel is not receiving any data via mixpanel-ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixpanel

I setup Mixpanel as follows

```
tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['MIXPANEL_TOKEN'])
tracker.people.set('User-1', {
        '$first_name' => 'Test',
        '$last_name' => 'Test'
    })
tracker.track('User-1', 'Onboarding visit')
```

No error/expecption is raised however I do not see any data in my Mixpanel project. `ENV['MIXPANEL_TOKEN']` is properly set. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem with Mixpanel receiving my landing page data (or any that I wanted to register).

I managed (after a day of struggle with it) to solve it by turning off my adblocker, yeah, go figure that one out.

Hopefully this will solve yours too!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is good to use Mixpanel error handler which helps finding problems in execution.

```
class MyErrorHandler < Mixpanel::ErrorHandler
  def initialize
  end
  def handle(error)
    puts "#{error.inspect}\n Backtrace: #{error.backtrace}"
  end
end
```

Mixpanel tracker initiation:

```
Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['MIXPANEL_TOKEN'],  MyErrorHandler.new)
```

Now we can see the error in the console. My problem was:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

So I knew that my problem is related to SSL handshake. I found a quick solution quickly afterwards: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-ruby/issues/83